# Exclude excel filter from auto filter

Tags: excel, vba, filter

This code works fine:

```
Sheet2.UsedRange.AutoFilter 28, Bad_list_a(), xlFilterValues
```

However I want to "<>" **Exclude** Bad_list_a() from autofilter, any suggestion?

Comment: what is Bad_list_a() ? Is it a range or an array or just a string string?

Comment: Further, you can't use "<>" for an array in autofilter, Alternatively you can use a range that contains the values that you want to include in filter.

Comment: @ScriptDeveloper Its string (a list)

Answer (score 1):

This is alternative way to exclude array from autofilter.

titles is an array that contains the values to exclude from autofilter. in your case Bad_list_a().
This code copy the column (that you want to filter) to sheet1, remove duplicates.

Then it deletes all the cells that matches with titles array. Finally, it will autofilter the column with remaining values that you need.

```
titles = Array("string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5", "string6", "string7", "string8", "string9")
    .Columns(columnToFilter).Copy
        sheet1.Range("J1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        sheet1.Range("J:J").RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes
    
 Set rngTitle = macroSheet.Range("I:I")
    rngTitle.Value = Application.Transpose(titles)
    
    For Z = 1 To sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sheet1.Range("I:I"), sheet1.Cells(Z, 10).Value) > 0 Then
    sheet1.Cells(Z, 10).Delete
    Z = Z - 1
    End If
    Next Z
    
    lastrowMacro = macroSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngcrit = macroSheet.Range("J1:J" & lastrowMacro).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    vCrit = rngcrit.Value
    
    ''Apply filter for error values of title
    .Range("1:1").AutoFilter Field:=columnToFilter, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(vCrit), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```